# Conditional array formulas

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a massive dataset and am preparing a dashboard based on this dataset.

On my dashboard, I have a drop-down menu that allows me to select a month of my choice, from Jan to Apr.

```
Visitor Jan Feb Mar Apr
Jenny   2   3   0   1  
Peter   2   0   1   3  
Charley 0   2       4  
Charley 1   2   2   3  
Sam     1   4   2   3  
Peter   2   2   5   0  
John    3   3   6   9  
Robin   4   0   7   0
```

I am looking for a formula that will give me the number of unique visitors who have been active at least once in the month that I choose from the drop-down menu.

Hoping this is really clear, but if not, please feel free to shoot back your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier with Excel 2013, but if the results you want from your example are `6`, `5`, `5`, and `5` for Jan>April respectively then perhaps:

1. Create a PivotTable from multiple consolidation ranges (example how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120) and for VALUES choose Sum of Value.
2. Count the non-zero values in the PT by column with a formula such as:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(H5:H10,">"&0)
   ```

The above however would not be convenient for repetition each month, though a whole year might be prepared at one time.